# How to access link InnerHTML using Selenium?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on this link using selenium IWebDriver commands.  I do not have access to the commands that I did when I was trying to use the browser control.

```
<a href="#" onclick="recentlyVisitedSelect('pages/VIEW/UTMEntry.aspx?USParams=PK=ESS!MenuID=2147!PageRerId=2147!ParentRerId=72','72','2147','2147', false, false, 'Time Clock Entry', true)" title="Time Clock Entry">
                Time Clock Entry</a>
```

The way I gained access to this link in the browser control was...

```
HtmlElement link = (from HtmlElement elem in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
                                    where elem.InnerHtml == "Time Clock Entry"
                                    select elem).ElementAt(0);
                link.InvokeMember("Click");
```

The most recent failed attempt I have made using selenium is...

```
string elemHTML = browser.FindElement(By.LinkText("Time Clock Entry")).GetAttribute("innerHTML");
```

And...

```
IWebElement TCE = browser.FindElement(By.Id("Time Clock Entry"));
TCE.Click();
```

It would be simple I think, if I could figure out a way to access the InnerHTML.

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I would just select by css selector using the title and tag.

```
By.cssSelector("a[title='Time Clock Entry']");
```

Comment: Awesome idea!  It, however returned the same error all of my other attempts did... Unhandled exception has occurred... Unable to find element with css selector == a[title='Time Clock Entry'].

Comment: @SeanConnelly This is the correct way to do this... is this element in an iframe or hidden somehow?

Comment: If you look at the section of code above that starts with "HtmlElement link" it works perfectly when used in a webBrowser control.  The problem is that there is a button on the next page after this that is in an iFrame that I can not seem to access.  I am trying to convert that first line of code in the following way, but the "from" is causing an error...  HtmlElement link = (from HtmlElement elem in browser.FindElement(By.TagName("a"))